# Table Pivot in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have a table of phone numbers connected to persons, and the numbers are already partitioned by the person ID:

```
person_id   number      row_count
1           5556667777  1
1           5435346523  2
1           7645634344  3
2           5556667777  1
2           5435346523  2
3           7645634344  1
```

The amount of numbers per person can reach up to twenty, but I already have them sequenced by priority, and want to make five columns of the first five numbers per person, leave `null` the empty colums and ignore numbers past the fifth column:

```
person_id   num_1       num_2       num_3       num_4       num_5
1           5556667777  5435346523  7645634344  null        null
2           5556667777  5435346523  null        null        null
3           7645634344  null        null        null        null
```

I have been looking around and it looks like `pivot` is the right command, but I can't wrap my head around a similar enough example to fully understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PIVOT` takes some time to get comfortable with, but luckily your case is a pretty straightforward example:

```
SELECT person_id, [1] Num_1,[2] Num_2,[3] Num_3,[4] Num_4,[5] Num_5
FROM Table1
PIVOT(MAX(number) FOR row_count IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5]))pvt
```

Demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/111ac/3/0)

Since you're only using 5 numbers and ignoring the rest, it's easy enough to hard-code in the 5 values used, but this can also be done dynamically.